# PHP Email contact-form

Tags: php

I've recently started using HTML, Javascript and PHP to create my own website.
I have been trying to make a PHP script that takes inputs from a form, validates with javascript and php, then sends the email.
I know the script is executed and runs fine, as it sucessfully redirects me to the new page at the end. However, it does not actually send any emails for some reason. 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
  $errors = '';
  $myemail = '<removed due to privacy>';
  if(empty($_POST['name'])  ||  empty($_POST['email']) ||  empty($_POST['message']))
  {
    $errors .= "\n Error: all fields are required";
  }

  $name = $_POST['name']; 
  $email_address = $_POST['email']; 
  $message = $_POST['message']; 

  if (!preg_match("/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,3})$/i", $email_address))
  {
    $errors .= "\n Error: Invalid email address";
  }

  if( empty($errors))
  {
    $to = $myemail;

    $email_subject = "Contact form submission: $name";

    $email_body = "You have received a new message. ".

    " Here are the details:\n Name: $name \n ".

    "Email: $email_address\n Message \n $message";

    $headers = "From: $myemail\n";

    $headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";

    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

    //redirect to the 'thank you' page

    header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html');

  }
?>
```

Now I did see a few similar questions, but as I am very incompetent at php, they didn't really help.
If you can identify the reason, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Are you developing in local or did you host your page somewhere?

Comment: You need to do some debugging. What doesn't work? Does your code get as far as calling `mail()`, or is one of your conditions triggering first? Also, if you have a look at the man page - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php - you need to end header lines with `\r\n`, and not just `\n`; that might be causing the problem

Comment: change your \n to\r\n as andrewsi suggested and check if mail() has been disabled.

Comment: @Phate01 I'm hosting it on a raspbery pi on my local network

Comment: @andrewsi I have done that, but it did not work. I think the user who answered has found the problem.

Comment: @darthmorf stupid question: have you properly configured mail parameters in php.ini?

Comment: @Phate01I have changed the 'anonymous ftp password' (which it said was my email adress), if that's what you mean. Can you help with the issue below? I can't find a linux version of that guide that I know would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $sent = mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
```

put a condition like this

```
if($sent){ header('Location: contact-form-thank-you.html'); } else { echo 'mail failed';}
```

if it show "mail failed" configure your localhost to sent mails

follow this tutorials

http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/

Comment: I got a 'mail failed'. Is there a linux version of that guide? It appeared to be for windows.